# Diabolo Fee-Brussels

Tags: trains, tickets, belgium, brussels

I have to travel to [Geel, Belgium](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Geel,+Belgium/@51.1659,4.9860499,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x47c14be5c4257adf:0x40099ab2f4d5110) from [Geneva, Switzerland](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Geneva,+Switzerland/@46.2050295,6.1440885,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x478c650693d0e2eb:0xa0b695357b0bbc39). I will go by plane to [Brussels](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Brussels,+Belgium/@50.854975,4.3753899,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x47c3a4ed73c76867:0xc18b3a66787302a7) and then I will the train(s) to Geel. Searching in [Belgian Rail](http://www.belgianrail.be/), I came accross a special ticket which i called the **Diabolo Fee**. i searched around to see, what exactly is that ticket and if it suits my needs, but I couldn't find any relevant and useful information.

Does anyone have any idea whatsoever on what exactly is that ticket and if I am able to use it to travel to Geel?

Comment: Look at the "web deal" - it might significantly cut your costs. I saved 30 euros last week because of it. Traveled from Brussels to Bruges for 6 euros.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum : Thank you very much for your advice! The thing is that I am travelling to Belgium on the 14th of December so I have to wait probably a bit longer!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The diabolo fee is something you have to pay on top of a regular ticket to the airport, to fund the extension of the [Diabolo project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diabolo_project). A regular ticket to or from the airport bought from the NMBS/SNCB already includes it. But it's also sold separately for people who only need to pay the extra fee because they have a rail card or another type of ticket that does not include the fee (e.g. tickets bought in the Netherlands used not to include it, not sure if that's still the case).

The Diabolo fee ‘stand-alone’ ticket is not in itself a valid ticket and you cannot travel only with that. See also [this PDF](http://www.belgianrail.be/en/travel-tickets/tickets/%7E/media/624A51E5F4E648A2B3783531522C37E0.ashx) from the National Rail company.

See also [Is it possible to change tracks in the train station of Brussels Airport Zaventem without a Diabolo Pass?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157664/is-it-possible-to-change-tracks-in-the-train-station-of-brussels-airport-zavente/157676#157676) on how things look at the airport.