# Is it possible to change tracks in the train station of Brussels Airport Zaventem without a Diabolo Pass?

Tags: airports, train-stations, brussels

I was just wondering if it were possible to go e.g. from track 1 to track 2 without needing to go through any gates that require a Diabolo Pass. I'm not planning on visiting the airport, just the train station.

Comment: I assume you will use a valid ticket on the train. Can you tell us what kind of ticket?

Comment: Note that while possible, this may not be allowed, see article 55 of http://www.belgianrail.be/de/kundendienst/beforderungsbedingungen/~/media/22447F8E4AEF49059982F8D21C6FE460.pdf unless you specifically book a ticket with a stop or connection at the station.

Comment: @relaxed: It is not possible to "book" a ticket with a "stop" at a station. Belgian traintickets are always open origin-to-destination tickets. As such you don't book anything, and you are allowed to take any permitted route on your ticket. So if you have a ticket that has a permitted route that involves a change at Brussels Airport you are allowed to do exactly that.

Comment: @KristvanBesien Sure, it's possible: book two tickets, one from anywhere to the airport and another one from the airport to another station. Not that it matters much to the point I was making.

Answer (score 8):

It should be possible. The Diabolo surcharge is checked at a row of automated gates between the foyer of the train station and the rest of the airport. You can go up and down the stairs leading to the platforms and around the foyer before going through the gates. Facilities are minimal (maybe a toilet and of course some machines to buy a Diabolo pass if your ticket doesn't include it) and staff is there to guide the people leaving to the airport through this peculiar process.

That's how I remember it and it is confirmed by the [Belgian Railways website](https://www.belgiantrain.be/en/tickets-and-railcards/airports/diabolo-fee):

> It is still possible to take a connecting service at Brussels Airport-Zaventem station, without having to pass through the gates.